# How to copy a vector to a subvector of another vector without segfaulting?

Tags: c++, vector, c++14

I have some code that looks like this:

```
for (int = i; i > (chip.rom.size() - 1); i++) {
        //int i = 0;
        chip.memory[i + 512] = chip.rom[i];
        //i++;

}
```

`chip` is a struct where memory and rom are both vectors of unsigned chars

`rom` is a vector of 160 bytes which is the game rom that I'm using to test my emulator.

`memory` is zeroed to 4096 bytes like so:

```
chip.memory = std::vector<BYTE>(4096);
```

Upon debugging, I managed to found out that I was seg faulting after this for statement. I feel like im going crazy! What obvious error am I missing?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to go through the [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) on what and how you can ask here. It's especially important to post a [mcve].

Comment: you don't initialize i

Comment: Ok, Thanks for the link!

Comment: @Sopel Thanks. I can't believed I missed that. Although my second vector, chip.memory, doesn't change (Its still zeroed out).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't initialize `i` and your comparison is in the wrong direction. Also, if you use `<` for your comparison, the `- 1` is unnecessary if you're just trying to avoid running off the end of `chip.rom`.

You shouldn't even be using a loop at all here really. Here's how the code ought to read:

```
#include <algorithm>  // Somewhere up above

::std::copy(chip.rom.begin(), chip.rom.end(), chip.memory.begin() + 512);
```

Use the stuff from the `<algorithm>` header and you don't have to remember to get everything in your `for` statement correct all the time. Not only that, but it's likely your compiler will generate more efficient code.

Comment: better way is to use `.assign(first, last)`

Comment: @АлексейНеудачин OP wants to write to an existing location, not have two identical vectors

Comment: yeah it should be `.insert(where , first, last)`

Comment: overall  `memcpy` is preffered method for this kind of stuff. and `std::string` is better then vector for bytes.But you still could do `memcpy(&vect[0] + 512 , ..)`